# python - call a function from a list item

Tags: python

I want to call a function named in the dictionary depending on the key called.

Example:

```
start_options = {'left': 'octopus', 'right': 'lion', 'small': 'pit', 'small door': 'pit'}

choice = raw_input("What do you want to do? ").lower()
        if choice in dictionary:
            print "found: " + choice, start_options[choice]
            print "You chose " + choice
            #code here will call function

def octopus():
    #do something
```

Comment: If you define `octopus` *before* `start_options`, you can make *the function itself* the value.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python

Answer (score 2):

If you define the functions beforehand, you can then refer to them directly in your dictionary as opposed to string representations:

```
def yada():
    print("Yada!")

def blah():
    print("Blah!")

start_options = {'test1': yada, 'test2': blah}
start_options['test1']()
```

Running this code produces:

> Yada!

Comment: This worked, thanks. However there was an issue that nobody spotted, my dictionary values were in quotes that had to be removed

Comment: @DarrenRyan That was something I noticed but forgot to mention. I'll edit my answer.